# Unnest a two-dimensional array to a table

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to convert the following into a two-columned table?

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([[1,'a'],[2,'b'], [3,'c']) AS tbl (num,str);
```

Or more generally into a table of `n` columns where `n` is the size of the inner array (i.e., the length of a row).

The array structure is `arr[rows][cols]`

Comment: Your array is invalid. Show what you actually have. Is it an array of records? Like `ARRAY [ROW(1,'a'),(2,'b'), (3,'c')]` = `'["(1,a)","(2,b)","(3,c)"]'`? And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in PostgreSQL can contain elements of one type (but it can be composite type). So array like `array[1,2,'e']` is invalid in PostgreSQL.

What can be done is to unnest two arrays in one statement

```sql
SELECT UNNEST(array[1,2,3]),unnest(array['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: oh that's so cool. How does Postgres align the arrays and all? I've never seen another database that can do it like that.

Comment: by element index. And if one array has less elements than another then nulls are served.
`SELECT UNNEST(array[1,2,3]),unnest(array['a','b','c','D'])`

Comment: is there a way to inline an aggregate function, such as `SUM(UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3]))` ? Or is the only way to do it something like the following: `SELECT sum(num) FROM (
  SELECT UNNEST(array[1,2,3]) num, UNNEST(array['a','b','c']) letter
) tbl (num, letter)` ?

Comment: `SELECT sum(num) FROM UNNEST(array[1,2,3]) a(num)`

Comment: is there any way though to shove that into the select_list? For example: `SELECT
    sum(num) FROM UNNEST(array[1,3,5]) AS num,
    sum(num) FROM UNNEST(array[1,2,3]) AS num` ?

Comment: `select sum(elem1), sum(elem2) from (
SELECT UNNEST(array[1,2,3]) elem1 ,unnest(array[3,4,5])  elem2
) a`